# How to make a bottom tab bar in android?

Tags: android

I am using this code to put bottom tab bar in android but it does not appear in my layout pages in the app. also I made the maintab.xml and other tab required files in the drawable. but still it does not work. Can you please tell me what is wrong ?

```
  public class TabbottonActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maintab);
        setTabs() ;
    }
    private void setTabs()
    {
        addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, MenuActivity.class);
        addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_search, DestinationActivity.class);

        addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, MenuActivity.class);
        addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_search, DestinationActivity.class);
    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use bottom tab bars

> Don't use bottom tab bars
>   Tther platforms use the bottom tab bar to switch between the app's views. Per platform convention, Android's tabs for view control are shown in action bars at the top of the screen instead. In addition, Android apps may use a bottom bar to display actions on a split action bar.
>
> You should follow this guideline to create a consistent experience
>   with other apps on the Android platform and to avoid confusion between
>   actions and view switching on Android.

From: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

**Edit:**
How you should create tabs

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: but the original code works properly , but when I integrated it with my app it does not work!

Comment: Make sure there isn't something wrong in your layout file (maintab.xml).

Comment: Everything is the same I just changed the classes that I wanted it shows after I clicked for example on the home . these lines were changed:
    addTab("Home", R.drawable.tab_home, MenuActivity.class);
        addTab("Search", R.drawable.tab_search, DestinationActivity.class);

Comment: Don't use TabActivity, it's deprecated (This class was deprecated in API level 13). See the link in my answer to create tabs the right way

Comment: but there is not any suggestion that how I am able to make a button bar in my app? I want to put the home bottom and  back bottom inside my app instead of using them from your cellphone. I will appreciate if you can help me.